# SSH - How can I answer "[fingerprint]" to the "connection" prompt and what does it do?

Tags: ssh

I looked in the man page for ssh, but I am still clueless. When you connect to the remote host using ssh it shows something like this:

```
ssh user@10.11.12.13
The authenticity of host '10.11.12.13 (10.11.12.13)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:CwrcHjdd9349u38rj392fr9j389rj3298rj23.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

As I understand:

- Yes - connect and write the fingerprint in the known hosts file
- No - do not connect (it shows "Host key verification failed.")

**What is that 3rd option [fingerprint]?**

Comment: It's not really relevant to your question, but if you answer "yes", what gets added to the known hosts file is the host's public key, not the fingerprint.

Comment: Yes. The known_hosts file contains public keys. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Related: [What is a SSH key fingerprint and how is it generated?](https://superuser.com/q/421997/87805)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This prompt allows you to paste *the actual fingerprint* as a response; ssh itself will compare it against the public key seen over the network. If both match, the answer is assumed to be `yes`.

(Of course, you're supposed to copy the fingerprint from a reasonably trusted source – not from the same confirmation message!)

In addition to being faster than manual comparison, this avoids ["fuzzy fingerprint"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.8211&rep=rep1&type=pdf) attacks where the fake host­key has a fingerprint that is visually *similar* to the real one (as people often look only at the first and last few letters and skip the rest).

This feature was added in OpenSSH 8.0.

Comment: Fine, but how in the heck do you format it? I had the computer owner run "ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key" and send me the output through a trusted channel, but every combination just returns "Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint:"

Comment: For the record, this "helpful" response occurs if you simply put a key that doesn't match...

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @user1686's answer, at least for my ssh client (OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6 on Mac) the behavior when typing an *incorrect* key is confounding. Rather than presenting a message like "Keys don't match, exiting!" it just responds with "Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint:", leaving you to wonder if you have the right format...

It *does* accept the correct fingerprint, when entered as "`{HASH_TYPE}:{HASH_FINGERPRINT}`", e.g. `SHA256:6IwH4s6MTcIsiC6vol79ODXqdFH1E3/qp/fQVj4jZ5q` AND for the correct key type, negotiated earlier in the connection process.

Make sure you are checking the right key if the host has multiple types!